# Find caller IP of Google Cloud Functions V2

Tags: google-cloud-functions

There is just no way to find out who calls a Cloud Functions V2 function. All methods return null.

I tried:

`X-Client-IP X-Forwarded-For CF-Connecting-IP Fastly-Client-Ip  True-Client-I X-Real-IP X-Cluster-Client-IP X-Forwarded, Forwarded-For and Forwarded appengine-user-ip req.connection.remoteAddress req.socket.remoteAddress req.connection.socket.remoteAddress req.info.remoteAddress Cf-Pseudo-IPv4`

All are null

Answer (score 1):

The client's IP address is in the HTTP header `X-Forwarded-For`. That header will contain the IP address of the remote system that connected to the GFE.

Comment: I tried this in a V2 functions emulator and the header is null

Comment: @VidicanVlad-Radu - Edit your post and show the code that is processing the HTTP headers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example